# Setting scrollbar position on Full Calendar horizontal view

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, scrollbar, fullcalendar-scheduler

We are using full calendar time view and more specifically the timeline view.

It works great however there is one issue which is very frustrating and that is when you access year view and the scrollbar defaults to January as it is the furthest left.

There is no internal option to set the scroll start point

The demo is viewable here by accessing the link below and then clicking "Year"

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-custom-view-demo

[image]

How could we set the scrollbar and div to default to the current month or at least set by a number with a work around.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: if you want it to go to a specific month then you have to use the "resourceTimelineMonth" view which shows one month at a time. Click the "month" button on the demo. You can then press next/previous to jump precisely between the months. Each view always starts the earliest time point represented by that view.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old now. It seems it is fixed.

Now, there is the possibility to set a scroll time:

```
scrollTime: '08:00'
```

It is described here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v6/scrollTime

If you want to set to May, use:

```
scrollTime: '4000:00'
```

But for some reason it does not work above 7000 hours.

Answer (score 0):

On V6 you need to do the following:

```
datesSet: function(dateInfo){
    // Get how many days the difference to what is shown to now is
    const diffDays = Math.abs(new Date() - dateInfo.start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    // Scroll by that many days (you can include years, hours, etc.)
    dateInfo.view.calendar.scrollToTime({days:diffDays});
},
```